# How to retrieve data from DSPACE using SyndicationFeed

Tags: dspace

Background:

We currently have an existing application that can retrieve data from EPRINTS repository but one of the new clients is using a DSPACE repository.

From what I noticed, the query URL for EPRINTs when browsed provides an XML type, example:

university eprints domain?_action_export=1&output=RSS2&exp=0%7c1%7c-date%2fcreators_name%2ftitle%7carchive%7c-%7cq%3a_fulltext_%2fabstract%2fcreators_name%2fdate%2fdocuments%2feditors_name%2ftitle%3aALL%3aIN%3amusic%7c-%7ceprint_status%3aeprint_status%3aANY%3aEQ%3aarchive%7cmetadata_visibility%3ametadata_visibility%3aANY%3aEQ%3ashow

Now, I want to retrieve data from DSPACE repository. How can I create the query URL?
This is the existing code that I am using:

```
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
            var XmlReaderSettings_ = new XmlReaderSettings();
            XmlReaderSettings_.XmlResolver = null;
            XmlReaderSettings_.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;

            using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(stream, XmlReaderSettings_))
            {
                var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xr);
                return feed.Items.ToList();
            }
```

Comment: It might help you get good answers if you could give an example of the information you'd like to retrieve about each item.

Comment: I was able to find the solution for this one. The query URL for DSPACE to get RSS feed format is that the "open-search" should be enabled. Sample URl query will be: http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/open-search/?query=test&start=0&rpp=10&format=rss

Answer (score 2):

If you view the page source on the DSpace site, the RSS and Open Search URL's should be available in source.

```
<link type="application/rss+xml" rel="alternate" href="/feed/rss_1.0/site" />
<link type="application/rss+xml" rel="alternate" href="/feed/rss_2.0/site" />
<link type="application/atom+xml" rel="alternate" href="/feed/atom_1.0/site" />
<link type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" rel="search" href="https://siteid:443/open-search/description.xml" title="DSpace" />
```